# JQuery ready event and its shortcut

Tags: javascript, jquery

In most of the videos, I see expert JQuery developers writing complete code for the `ready` event eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //.....
});
```

rather than its shortcut:

```
$(function(){
  //.....
});
```

Is there any particular down side to using shortcut method?

### Edit:

Jquery documentation says:

**shortcut not recommended**

That's my question, why is it not recommended? Should we ever use it in our projects?

Comment: Where does the jQuery documentation say that the `$(function() { ... })` form is deprecated?

Comment: @Pointy: please see the answer of Dancrumb, also i myself had read it somewhere.

Comment: That information is clearly wrong.  Read that jQuery document *carefully* and you'll see that it's talking about calling the jQuery function **with no arguments.** The "ready" shortcut is **not that case** since it involves passing a function.

Comment: +1, I'm interested in the answer too.

Comment: @Pointy : I overlooked the $(function(){...}) case indeed, but all I stated is that the doc is outdated and IT IS in that it mentions the $().ready(...) case which is, this one, deprecated.

Comment: But $().ready(function() { ... }) does still work. Nothing in that documentation you've referenced suggests that $().ready() should not be used.

Comment: My misunderstanding. Thought that since $() is no longer equivalent to $(document), that implied that $().ready wasn't any longer equivalent to $(document).ready .... It looks like I was wrong and made some wrong assumptions. I think I'll debug what's going on with $().ready, at least I'll try to learn a lesson out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question... sometimes these shortcuts breed as much confusion as convenience.

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
> * $(document).ready(handler)
> * $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
> * $(handler)
> ```

EDIT

`$().ready(handler)` is not recommended in the documentation and, in the latest version of jQuery, will **not** work.

In older versions of jQuery, `$(document)` and `$()` were equivalent. Per the [jQuery site](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards), this is no longer the case

Comment: @Dancrumb: I forgot to mention that too. Why jquery documentation says shortcut way is not recommended, any particular reason for that, should we use it assuming it will never ever create problems?

Comment: Dancrumb, please edit anything to your reply so I can remove the negative vote (I sincerely thought it was wrong)

Comment: Sorry @David. Looks like you'll have to live with this guilt forever :P

Answer (score 1):

[They are equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Actually, the doc is not up to date, see http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards

Comment: @Jer: I forgot to mention that too. Why jquery documentation says shortcut way is not recommended, any particular reason for that, should we use it assuming it will never ever create problems?

Comment: @David, you're misreading the documentation. The change was only to the no-argument call, not the call that passes in a "ready" handler function.

Comment: The doc mentions $().ready( callback ), and this no longer works. My statements that the doc is outdated stands.

Comment: You're wrong, @David. That does work. Here's a demo page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/ready.html

Comment: Well my argument was from this sentence in the link I provided : jQuery() (with no arguments) no longer converts to jQuery(document).

I stand corrected, and I will go hide in in shame in a corner now.

Comment: @David spoken like a gentleman - my shame corner is warm most of the time :-)

Comment: @Pointy, +1 for the domain name of your demo page :-D

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut ( to $().ready( callback ) ) is no longer valid as of jQuery 1.4

Edit: starting with jQuery 1.4, $() is the empty jQuery object.

This is explained here : http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards

Comment: That is absolutely wrong.  The "shortcut" most certainly does NOT pass nothing to the function - it passes a function.

Comment: The jQuery function's prototype object has a "ready" function, so $().ready(...) is effectively the same as $(document).ready(...).

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood the link I posted and would (sincerely) greatly appreciate that you explain for me this statement : jQuery() (with no arguments) no longer converts to jQuery(document).  ---- I had assumed that $().ready worked as $(document).ready because $() was the same as $(document).

Answer (score 1):

I think all answers have already clarified that `$().ready(function)` is not recommended.

`$(function)` is the other shortcut and all with all shortcuts its upto you to decide whether the gain of writing **16** lesser character outweighs the loss of clarity for your purposes.

Comment: All those clarifications are wrong, and in any case *that was not the "shortcut" mentioned in the original question!*

Comment: I meant `$().ready(function)` is not recommended because that's where all the discussion seemed to be heading. Internally jQuery ignores the passed-in document object altogether in the ready() call , so as a leaked abstraction `$().ready()` works just like `$(document).ready()`. In any case, I have tried to answer the question about the shortcut in OPs question too.